# (502) Bad Gateway PhantomJS driver initialize

Tags: c#, selenium, centos, phantomjs, .net-core

I'm using Selenium.WebDriver 3.8.0 in .NET Core app and trying to initialize PhantomJS driver like this:

```
PhantomJSDriverService driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService("<path to PhantomJS binary file>", "phantomjs");
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
driverService.Proxy = "{my proxy address}:{port}";
driverService.ProxyType = "http";

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService, options);
```

When I run on CentOS:

> [INFO  - 2018-01-15T13:28:48.526Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 46847
>   The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
>   The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway. ... The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.

If I use the default constructor:`IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();`, the same error occurs.

In CentOS system proxy is configured in /etc/profile like this:

```
MY_PROXY_URL="{my proxy address}:{port}"
HTTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
HTTPS_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
FTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
http_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
https_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
ftp_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
export HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy
```

What could be the problem? I learned all the queries in Google about Selenium, PhantomJS and CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cause of 502 Bad Gateway Errors
>   Bad Gateway errors are often caused by issues between online servers that you have no control over.
>   [Source](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939)

There is probably some issue on the server end, so as you see, there is probably nothing you can do unless the server is yours. I doesn't have to do with your constructor.

> However, sometimes, there is no real issue but your browser thinks there is one thanks to an issue with your browser, a problem with your home networking equipment, or some other in-your-control reason.
>   [Source](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939)

On the other hand, it might be an issue with your configuration. There are some things you can do and try to fix it here: [Fix 502 Bad Gateway Error](http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-502-bad-gateway-error/), they might help you out if it's really a problem on your end.